# event.preventDefault() not working inside of .then

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

Code:

```
angular
  .module('mean-starter')
  .run(run)
;

function run($rootScope, Auth, $state) {
  function preventStateChange (message, event, redirect) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(message);

    if (redirect) {
      $state.go(redirect);
    }
  }

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
    if (typeof toState.authenticate === 'undefined') { // this route doesn't require permissions
      return;
    }

    event.preventDefault(); // WORKS HERE

    Auth
      .getCurrentUser()
      .then(function (currentUser) {
        event.preventDefault(); // DOESN'T WORK HERE
        var isLoggedIn = !!currentUser._id;
        var isAdmin = isLoggedIn && currentUser.role === 'admin';
        var isAuthorized = isLoggedIn && currentUser._id.toString() === toParams.id;

        if (toState.authenticate.loggedOut && isLoggedIn) { // this route requires you to be logged out
          preventStateChange("You're logged in.", event);
        }
        else if (!isLoggedIn) {
          preventStateChange('Must be logged in to access this route.', event, 'login');
        }
        else if (toState.authenticate.authorized && !isAuthorized && !isAdmin) {
          preventStateChange('You are not authorized to access that route.', event);
        }
        else if (toState.authenticate.isAdmin && !isAdmin) {
          debugger;
          event.preventDefault();
          preventStateChange('You must be an admin to access this route.', event);
        }
      })
    ;
  });
}
```

When I'm logged in as a non-admin and I go to `localhost:3000/admin`:

1. I get an alert saying, "You must be an admin to access this route."
2. I get taken to the admin page, and can see all of the admin stuff that I'm not supposed to be able to see.

Why is this?

When I inspect in the debugger, `event.preventDefault` is defined, and it seems to get called. This is the `event` object that gets logged out to the console:

[image]

It's `defaultPrevented` property gets set to `true`!

---

UPDATE: It works outside of the `.then`, but it does NOT work inside of the `.then`. Which is surprising because it is defined inside of the `.then`.

---

UPDATE 2: My guess is that the `event` does it's default action BEFORE it reaches the `.then`. And so essentially, `.then` is too late.

Comment: add `$state.go('/login');` after `event.preventDefault();`. This should redirect the user to the login page instead of showing the admin content.

Comment: @JoshuaK that isn't (always) what I want to do. Even if it was, I still would like to know why this isn't working.

Comment: `event` shouldn't be being overridden. It's defined in the local scope(s).

Comment: you are right. that was bad. your screenshot shows that it is the right event.

Comment: ah another question: if you call `localhost:3000/admin`. is it the first state? `event.preventDefault()` prevents the change of the state. but if there is no fromState there occur an error.

Comment: Your update #2 is correct, it will not work inside `.then()`.  By definition, the code in `.then()` will run in the next event loop (asynchronously) so the default action will have already taken place.

Comment: @aarosil that sounds like an answer to me :) Is there a reason you put it as a comment instead of an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second guess is essentially correct. The browser actions are resolved after all the current event handlers have returned. In fact, one of the mechanisms to prevent default action (the original mechanism actually) was to have the event handler return `false` or `0` to cancel default action. So it happens semi-synchronously - it happens inside an asynchronous function but is resolved at the end of the current event loop.

The only way around it is to call `.preventDefault()` before calling your promise.